# How to pass event parameters in condition function in pytransition

Tags: python, transition, fsm, pytransitions

I am trying to pass a parameter to conditions. But it was giving the following error

code:

```
from transitions import Machine

class evenodd(object):
    def get_no(self, event):
        self.no = event.kwargs.get('no', 0)
    def calc_mod(self, event):
        self.mod = event.kwargs.get('mod', self.no%2)
    
    def is_even(self, event):
        if self.mod == 0:
            return True
        
obj = evenodd()
machine = Machine(obj, ['init', 'getno', 'even', 'odd'], send_event=True, initial='init', ignore_invalid_triggers=True, auto_transitions=False)
machine.add_transition('enterno', 'init', 'getno', before='get_no')
machine.add_transition('isevenodd', 'getno', 'even', before='calc_mod', conditions=['is_even'])
machine.add_transition('isevenodd', 'getno', 'odd', before='calc_mod', conditions=['is_odd']) 


s_state = obj.state
print("state --> "+s_state)
trigger = machine.get_triggers(s_state)[0]
print("transition --> "+trigger)
obj.enterno(2)
s_state = obj.state
print("state --> "+s_state)
trigger = machine.get_triggers(s_state)[0]
print("transition --> "+trigger)
obj.isevenodd()
s_state = obj.state
print("state --> "+s_state)
```

Error:

```
state --> init
transition --> enterno
state --> getno
transition --> isevenodd
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-d8ede3775dc5> in <module>
      8 trigger = machine.get_triggers(s_state)[0]
      9 print("transition --> "+trigger)
---> 10 obj.isevenodd()
     11 s_state = obj.state
     12 print("state --> "+s_state)

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_nlp_cpu\lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py in trigger(self, model, *args, **kwargs)
    388         # Machine._process should not be called somewhere else. That's why it should not be exposed
    389         # to Machine users.
--> 390         return self.machine._process(func)
    391 
    392     def _trigger(self, model, *args, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_nlp_cpu\lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py in _process(self, trigger)
   1112             if not self._transition_queue:
   1113                 # if trigger raises an Error, it has to be handled by the Machine.process caller
-> 1114                 return trigger()
   1115             else:
   1116                 raise MachineError("Attempt to process events synchronously while transition queue is not empty!")

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_nlp_cpu\lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py in _trigger(self, model, *args, **kwargs)
    406                 raise MachineError(msg)
    407         event_data = EventData(state, self, self.machine, model, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
--> 408         return self._process(event_data)
    409 
    410     def _process(self, event_data):

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_nlp_cpu\lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py in _process(self, event_data)
    415             for trans in self.transitions[event_data.state.name]:
    416                 event_data.transition = trans
--> 417                 if trans.execute(event_data):
    418                     event_data.result = True
    419                     break

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_nlp_cpu\lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py in execute(self, event_data)
    260         _LOGGER.debug("%sExecuted callbacks before conditions.", event_data.machine.name)
    261 
--> 262         if not self._eval_conditions(event_data):
    263             return False
    264 

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_nlp_cpu\lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py in _eval_conditions(self, event_data)
    241     def _eval_conditions(self, event_data):
    242         for cond in self.conditions:
--> 243             if not cond.check(event_data):
    244                 _LOGGER.debug("%sTransition condition failed: %s() does not return %s. Transition halted.",
    245                               event_data.machine.name, cond.func, cond.target)

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_nlp_cpu\lib\site-packages\transitions\core.py in check(self, event_data)
    179         predicate = event_data.machine.resolve_callable(self.func, event_data)
    180         if event_data.machine.send_event:
--> 181             return predicate(event_data) == self.target
    182         return predicate(*event_data.args, **event_data.kwargs) == self.target
    183 

<ipython-input-74-5dc86072aabd> in is_even(self, event)
      7     def is_even(self, event):
      8         """ Basically a coin toss. """
----> 9         if self.mod == 0:
     10             return True
     11 

AttributeError: 'evenodd' object has no attribute 'mod'
```

How to share the variables no, and mod with each of these callbacks. I tried to use the event.
In this simple example, I tried to create a state machine to reach the state based on whether the given input is even or odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share variables as attributes of the model. You need to consider callback execution order though. According to `transitions` [documentation](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions#execution-order) callbacks are executed in that order:

- `'machine.prepare_event'`
- `'transition.prepare'`
- `'transition.conditions'`
- `'transition.unless'`
- `'machine.before_state_change'`
- `'transition.before'`
- `'state.on_exit'`
- `<STATE CHANGE>`
- `'state.on_enter'`
- `'transition.after'`
- `'machine.after_state_change'`
- `'machine.finalize_event'`

You can see that `before` is triggered **after** conditions have been evaluated and the transition *will definitely* happen. Thus, `self.mod` is not available in `is_even` since `calc_mod` has not been called yet. The list also shows how to deal with this: Execute `calc_mod` in `prepare` instead of `before`:

```
machine.add_transition('isevenodd', 'getno', 'even', prepare='calc_mod', conditions=['is_even'])
machine.add_transition('isevenodd', 'getno', 'odd', prepare='calc_mod', conditions=['is_odd'])
```

`prepare` has been introduced exactly for that use case where condition checks need some setup. If 'tear down' is also required, you can use `machine.finalize_event` which will always be called regardless whether a transition took place or not. Speaking of callback resolution order: You can pass condition checks to `unless` which will halt a transition if they evaluate to true. You could replace `conditions='is_odd'` with `unless='is_even'`.

If you don't mind some implicit logic you could discard the 'is_odd' check entirely. A set of valid triggers is always evaluated in the order they were added. This means that `'getno' -> 'odd'` will only be considered when `'getno' -> 'even'` has been found invalid. Design-wise, a transition without conditions which is added *last* will act as an 'else' clause which will be executed when no previous set of conditions could be met.

#### How to pass variables to callbacks

One way is to process the `event` object which is passed to callback when `send_event=True` on the machine. You can also pass variables as trigger parameters:

```
from transitions import Machine


class evenodd(object):

    def get_no(self, no=0, **kwargs):
        self.no = no

    def calc_mod(self, mod=None, **kwargs):
        self.mod = mod if mod else self.no % 2

    def is_even(self):
        return self.mod == 0


obj = evenodd()
machine = Machine(obj, ['init', 'getno', 'even', 'odd'], initial='init', 
                  ignore_invalid_triggers=True, auto_transitions=False)
machine.add_transition('enterno', 'init', 'getno', before='get_no')
machine.add_transition('isevenodd', 'getno', 'even', prepare='calc_mod', conditions=['is_even'])
machine.add_transition('isevenodd', 'getno', 'odd', prepare='calc_mod', conditions=['is_odd'])

obj.enterno(no=2)
obj.isevenodd()
print("state --> " + obj.state)
```

If you do that you must make sure that every callback can consume **all** parameters thrown at them. Using `kwargs` makes it quite easy though to 'discard' not required arguments. I'd also suggest *always* passing parameters as keyword arguments even though positional arguments are supported, too. In my experience, this makes code more comprehensible (e.g. easier to read method definitions) and reduces a source of error (e.g. wrong parameter mapping).